# Laravel: seeding error

Tags: laravel, faker

I'm trying to seed users table but I get following error:
    [ReflectionException]
    Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist

I don't know what is wrong, I did this many times with other tables and seeders.

**Here is my migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('initials');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    ...
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
...
$this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
...
```

**UsersTableSeeder.php**

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run() {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        User::create([
            'name'     => 'Some name',
            'surname'  => 'Some surname',
            'initials' => 'SI',
            'email'    => 'Some email',
            'password' => 'Some password',
        ]);
    }
}

...
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run `composer dump-autoload` and try once more